# filter not working on material tables when subscribing

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable, angular-material, ngrx

I am not able to filter table data when subscribing to the store in NGRX.

I have tried various ways of fetching and displaying the data The data table loads as expected but when I try to filter the data it simply filters everything out.

from component.ts

```
 export class CheckedInTableComponent implements OnInit {
  private subscription: ISubscription;
  // checkedInUsers: UserEvent[] = [];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<UserEvent>;
  userEvents: UserEvent[] = [];

  constructor(private checkinService: CheckinService) { }

  displayedColumns = ['name', 'supplier', 'visiting', 'dept', 'purpose', 'checkedIn', 'accessExpires', 'options'];

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.checkinService.setCheckedInUsers().subscribe(res => { this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<UserEvent>(res) });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

from service.ts

```
  setCheckedInUsers() {
    this.store.dispatch(new checkinActions.LoadCheckedin());
    return this.store.pipe(select(getEvents),map(res => {return this.checkedInUsers = res}))
  }
```

HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" fxLayoutGap="1rem grid" fxFill>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            {{element.user.title}} {{element.user.firstName}} {{element.user.lastName}}
        </td>
    </ng-container>
...
```

Comment: hm, looks good to me. can you reproduce in a plunkr / codepen / stackblitz or similar?

Comment: It wasn't working because my arrays were nested.  I to create a custom filter